# mp.stop() problem

Tags: android, button, android-widget, media-player

I am new to android,actually this is my second program.I am programming from last night and i am trying to find a solution for hours!!!I read everything here and i google my problem but i still cant fix it!!
My problem is the usual as i understood that i cannot stop audio playback when i click another button.I tried mp.release,stop,everything but keeps crashing when i press stop button or back!!What i am doing wrong??I have 22 buttons and i play 21 songs(one button at top for stop).
Also i forgot to mention that i tried to make button when clicking 2nd time to stop playing but i couldn't do it that's why i put stop button.

this is my code

```
package org.kidsongs;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class menu extends Activity {
    public MediaPlayer mp=null;
    Button playerButton;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);





        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01); 
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song1);                 
                    mp.start();




            }



        });


        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02); 
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song2);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });

        final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03); 
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song3);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04); 
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song4);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button05); 
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song5);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button06); 
        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song6);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button07); 
        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song7);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button08); 
        button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song8);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button09); 
        button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song9);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button10); 
        button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song10);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button11); 
        button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song11);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button12); 
        button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song12);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button13); 
        button13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song13);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button14); 
        button14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song14);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button15); 
        button15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song15);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button16);
        button16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song16);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button17 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button17); 
        button17.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song17);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button18 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button18); 
        button18.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song18);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button19); 
        button19.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song19);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button20 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button20); 
        button20.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song20);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button button21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button21); 
        button21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song21);                 
                    mp.start();



            }



        });


        final Button stopbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button22); 
        stopbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release(); 



            }



        }); 





    } 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.info, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mp.isPlaying()){ 
            mp.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace or you will not get a decent answer from anybody here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{                 
      MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song21);                 
      mp.start();
}
```

should be

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{                 
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song21);                 
       mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted is wrong, you are creating local MediaPlayer objects in each click handler. Use the object declared as a member of the activity instead, and then, when you call the stop method the reference will be established correctly.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song1);                 
                    mp.start();
            }
        });
```

should be:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song1);                 
                    mp.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The MediaPlayer instance of your activity class. You declared a MediaPlayer Object as a member of the class: 

public class menu extends Activity {
    public MediaPlayer mp=null;